# Policy checking length of depending posts

Tags: node.js, strapi

How can I write a policy to execute a route handler under specific contitions? In my blog app I want to make sure, that as an admin I can only remove a category if the one is not attached into any post. So I would like to check if given category to delete has no belonging posts.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check this documentation here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/policies.html#concept

You will have to create a policy and attach it to the `DELETE /category/:id` route.
Via `ctx.params` you will have access to the category id you want to delete.

In the policy, you will have to fetch the category and check if a post is related to this category.

`const cat = await strapi.api.category.services.category.findOne({id: ctx.params.id});`

You will have to `await next();` if all is OK or return a bad request if it's not OK.